# How to set position of image in silverlight

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, position

I've got the drag'n'drop image, which is located in ContentPanel. In MouseLeave event i get the position of image and then i need to align it to my grid. Tried to do it with Canvas, but nothing happens. When I try to do it changing the margin, the position is totally wrong.

Code:

```
private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Image rs = (Image)sender;
        GeneralTransform gt = rs.TransformToVisual(ContentPanel);
        Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        double controlTop = offset.Y;
        double controlLeft = offset.X;
        tb.Text = Convert.ToInt16(controlLeft / 40).ToString();
        tb2.Text = Convert.ToInt16(controlTop / 40).ToString();
        double newLeft = Convert.ToInt16(controlLeft / 40)*40;
        double newTop = Convert.ToInt16(controlTop / 40)*40;
        //rs.Margin = new Thickness(newLeft, newTop, 0, 0);
        //((Image)ContentPanel.Children[11]).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);
        //((Image)ContentPanel.Children[11]).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
    }
```

So how can I set the position of image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to apply a translate transformation to your image?

Something like that should work:

```
Image rs = (Image)sender;
GeneralTransform gt = rs.TransformToVisual(ContentPanel);
Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

//create a translate transform 
TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();

//apply the required offset
tt.X = offset.X;
tt.Y = offset.Y;

//apply the transform to the image
rs.RenderTransform = tt;

double controlTop = offset.Y;
double controlLeft = offset.X;
tb.Text = Convert.ToInt16(controlLeft / 40).ToString();
tb2.Text = Convert.ToInt16(controlTop / 40).ToString();
double newLeft = Convert.ToInt16(controlLeft / 40) * 40;
double newTop = Convert.ToInt16(controlTop / 40) * 40;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. TranslateTransform made everything just perfect.